# remove value in subform

Tags: ms-access

In one of my access forms I use a continuous sub form with just one field per line that creates an entry in a junction table.

While creating and changing entries in the junction form works fine, I have problems removing those entries. When I clear a line in the sub form, the entry should be deleted. Instead I get an alert message "Null value in index or primary key not possible".

I think I need some vb-programming to solve that problem, right? What would be a propper approach for that?

(I don't use MS-Access regularly so maybe I misused some technical terms. Please be kind.)

[edit]
I now use a delete button instead. I leave the topic open for the moment just in case somebody wants to add an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are (assumingly) using bound forms, every entry on your form is directly written into the table. Since your primary key is not allowed to be Null, it immediatly presents you with the alert.

There are different ways to solve this problem, depending on your goals.
If you want to allow empty entry's in the field that's momentarily your primary key, you should remove the key in the design view of your table.

If you want to disallow the empty entries, but want a custom error message or the message to appear after clicking a save button, you should change to an unbound form.

Comment: In fact I would want to have the record written to the table directly. But when the value of an entry in the sub form is deleted I would want to delete the whole record

Comment: Hmm, there are multiple ways to address this situation.
You might be able to add a check into the beforeupdate event of the field to see if the value is Null, and if so, delete the whole entry instead of firing the update event.
There is ofcourse also the possibilty to simply add a delete button for the selected record, which I would prefer, due to the greater flexibility for the end user.

Comment: ... I just realized a delete button can be added without any programming. Thanks!

Comment: perfect realization! Note that the preprogrammed delete button does not allow for some flexibility, but concerning your purpose it should probably be enoguh! Good luck